# Chose the right fields depend on another field value

Tags: java, json, apache-nifi, jolt

I wanted to know if there is way using jolt to select only fields that contain the value of another ?

Here is my input

```json
{
  "type": "A",
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "example1-A1[zone=fr,method=A]": "80",
  "example2-A1[zone=fr,method=A]": "90",
  "example1-B1[zone=fr,method=B]": "50",
  "example2-B1[zone=fr,method=B]": "10"
}
```

My output will depend on the value in the "type" field and check the method if it is equal to that type(eg: A) in order to select the values and will be like

```json
{
  "type": "A",
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2", 
  "new-filed1": "80", 
  "new-field2": "90"
}
```

Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 2):

Answer for the updated question:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*-*,method=*]": "fieldsByMethod.&(0,3).&(0,1)",
      "type": [
        "&",
        "otherFields.&"
      ],
      "*": "otherFields.&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "type": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,fieldsByMethod.&)": "&1"
        }
      },
      "otherFields": "otherFields"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "example*": "new-field&(0,1)",
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comparing the old and the updated input we have three additional requirements:

1. Fields without the `,method=` substring should also be in the output.
   For that we can temporarily place them in `otherFields` subdocument.
2. The `type` field should also be in the output:

That's why

```json
"type": [
    "&",
    "otherFields.&"
]
```

comes in handy. `&` rewrites the `type` field to it's original place, so we can use it as in the old answer. `otherFields.&` puts it also to the `otherFields` subdocument.

3. Rename the `example*` fields to `new-field*`. That happens in the last operation

---

Old answer for the spec:

```json
{
  "type": "A",
  "example1-A1[zone=fr,method=A]": "80",
  "example2-A1[zone=fr,method=A]": "90",
  "example1-B1[zone=fr,method=B]": "50",
  "example2-B1[zone=fr,method=B]": "10"
}
```

and the expected output:

```json
{
  "example1": "80", 
  "example2": "90"
}
```

This spec produces the expected output for the example:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "type": "type",
      "*-*,method=*]": "fieldsByMethod.&(0,3).&(0,1)"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "type": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,fieldsByMethod.&)": "&1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

---

To understand it, try to apply it step by step.

For the second (I think the trickiest one) operation I found the issue https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/480 that helped me to create it.

To understand the first operation, try to analyze the https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#prefixSoupToBuckets example.

Comment: Hi kasptom, it's really a wonderful solution !

Comment: Hello @kasptom thanks for your help, It fits to my need, however if we want to keep others fields from the input with the result and rename the example1 and example2 to new-field1 and new-field2 (as i've updated the post) Is it also possible based on your proposition ?

Comment: @Yawyaw1, I've updated the answer. Next time, feel free to ask another question. I would do that... I would even link the old  question to the new one and point out what are the new requirements.
The updated question seems like "level two" of the original "level one" :D

Comment: Thank you for your help @kasptom. But it seems a little tricky for my case, cause i have some other operations that don't help, i've asked a second question with more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71819470/filter-values-depends-on-another-field