# Filter values depends on another field

Tags: java, json, jolt

I have some issue finding the right way to filter in my input json file using jolt as described in the following:

**Input :**

```json
{
  "test1": 2242,
  "test2": 23456,
  "description": "desc, desc, desc",
  "name1": "foo",
  "active": true,
  "date1": "xx-xx-xx",
  "date2": "xx-xx-xx",
  "grade": "A",
  "quantity": 10,
  "information": "info, info, info",
  "favorite": "Y",
  "maxValue": 100,
  "approachTypeMin[zone=MAR, method=a]": "12",
  "approachTypeMax[zone=MAR, method=a]": "50",
  "approachTypeMin[zone=NOR, method=b]": "3",
  "approachTypeMax[zone=NOR, method=b]": "10"
}
```

This is my Spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "test1": "value1",
      "test2": "value2",
      "description": "desc1",
      "name1": "nameValue",
      "active": {
        "true": {
          "#Active": "status"
        },
        "false": {
          "#Inactive": "status"
        }
      },
      "date1": "beginDate",
      "date2": "endDate",
      "grade": {
        "*": {
          "$": "testGrade.value",
          "@(2,type)": "testGrade.type",
          "#2": "testGrade.defaultValue"
        }
      },
      "quantity": "qtn",
      "additionalInfo": "information",
      "favorite": "fvt",
      "maxValue": "max",
      "approachType*, method=*]": "test.&(0,2)"
    }
  }
]
```

This is my actual Output

```json
{
  "value1" : 2242,
  "value2" : 23456,
  "desc1" : "desc, desc, desc",
  "nameValue" : "foo",
  "status" : "Active",
  "beginDate" : "xx-xx-xx",
  "endDate" : "xx-xx-xx",
  "testGrade" : {
    "value" : "A",
    "defaultValue" : "2"
  },
  "qtn" : 10,
  "fvt" : "Y",
  "max" : 100,
  "test" : {
    "A" : [ "12", "50" ],
    "B" : [ "3", "10" ]
  }
}
```

My issue is that i can't find a way to get something like the result above depending on the grade(e.g grade A==Approach method):

```json
{
  "value1": 2242,
  "value2": 23456,
  "desc1": "desc, desc, desc",
  "nameValue": "foo",
  "status": "Active",
  "beginDate": "xx-xx-xx",
  "endDate": "xx-xx-xx",
  "value": "X",
  "testGrade": {
    "type": "A",
    "defaultValue": "2"
  },
  "qtn": "10",
  "fvt": "Y",
  "max": "100",
  "convertedApproachMin": 12,
  "convertedApproachMax": 50

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to divide key names starting with `approachType` one more time in order to seperate them by means of `Min` and `Max`, to derive the lower case grade to match the extracted methods (`a` and `b`).

So, use the following specs :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "test1": "value1",
      "test2": "value2",
      "description": "desc1",
      "name1": "nameValue",
      "active": {
        "true": {
          "#Active": "status"
        },
        "false": {
          "#Inactive": "status"
        }
      },
      "date1": "beginDate",
      "date2": "endDate",
      "grade": "&",
      "quantity": "qtn",
      "additionalInfo": "information",
      "favorite": "fvt",
      "maxValue": "max",
      "approachType*\\[zone*, method=*]": "cA&(0,1).&(0,3)"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "grade_l": "=toLower(@(1,grade))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "grade_l": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,grade)": "testGrade.value",
          "#2": "testGrade.defaultValue",
          "@(2,cAMin.&)": "convertedApproachMin",
          "@(2,cAMax.&)": "convertedApproachMax"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "grade": "",
      "cA*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ :

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros, it was exactly what i'm looking for you rock. I see that you added a & in the value of grade for handling the capital letter, is it possible to display this field with another  name in the output(eg: "grade_output": "A") ?

Comment: You're welcome @Yawyaw1 , you can rename it as using `"grade": "grade_output"` within the last shift transformation, and deleting the line `"grade": "",` from the remove transformation.